# Bower Install - Illegal instruction (core dumped)

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, bower

I'm trying to install client's app, written in Angular.js and in it's read.me there are following steps:

- npm install
- bower install
- cd electron
- npm install
- ./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild

And it should create 'vendors' folder while doing 'bower install' command. By running it, I get this message:

Illegal instruction (core dumped)

I don't know what can cause this problem

Node version: v8.10.0
Npm version: 3.5.2

By doing sudo npm install bower -g I'm getting this output:

```
/usr/local/bin/bower -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower 
/usr/local/lib bower@1.8.4
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with a very similar setup because I did not have java added to my PATH. After I verified I had java installed (openjdk 1.8.0_171) and added to PATH, the problem disappeared.